# Overriding android default camera/activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have requirement where in I have to overlay a header and footer over the camera. There is a set of three button which will handle the even of camera like (click/retake).

As of now i create a surface to use as preview and add jpegcallback and picture callback to take picture and store it. I manually handle android camera hardware and parameter configuration. As all of us know there has issues around camera and picture orientation. I have worked around this by setting camera orientation and also by rotating my captured image. Though the approach looks ugly i am able to achieve the end goal.

It would be great if we have a way of overriding the android default camera activity as any of the above steps are not required. I come from a Java/Java EE background and as per my understanding we should be able to create  a custom Activity and override the behaviors and properties.

**My Question:**

1. Can we override the activities for `android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and also `com.android.camera.action.CROP`.
2. If so which package of android has the java class for this activities.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I am not misunderstanding your question but it sounds like you want to use the camera in your app.  You want to view what the camera is seeing while having a header and footer above and below the camera preview.  Then you want these buttons to do things like take a picture, etc.

If I am wrong I apologize.

Just look at the Camera implementation in the docs.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

You can create your own activity layout with any buttons/text above, below, or on top of a preview view that you use to display the camera feed.  Then just use the on click events for the buttons or whatever to do the things you want.  Majority of this is in the documentation in the link.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I have done all this. But i had to do so much around camera orientation and working on the data captured by image etc. In a normal java world we would just extend parent and override the  behavior as per our requirement. Is that possible in Android. Can we extend a parent android activity and override certain sections of the activity??.

Comment: I am NEW Bee to android sorry if i am wrong . If i had to do croping on a image  i can use out of the box crop intent but that expects the image source to have  a URI but my application does not have a image URI rather i have stored my image as a Bytearray in global scope as application component. If we were able to extend default crop activity and provide the bitmap as the image source we can still use the croping feature of Android.

Comment: You can most certainly extend classes and then override the parent methods.  Just add '@Override' without the ' above the method in the extended (child) class that will be overriding the parent method.